# simple network between xp & 7 with cross cable problem

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-7, windows-xp, windows

i have a simple network between xp & 7 windowses with cross cable (2 pc home)...

=====================================================================

the one with 7 is mother and have 2 lan device (onboard + pci)

A.

onboard is like this when u go to tcp/ip v4 properties:(4 adsl internet)

obtain an ip...

preferred dns server : 81.91.129.67

alternate dns server : 4.2.2.4

shared...no permission 4 change

so every thing is ok for internet on windows 7.

B.

the other lan pci card that is connected to pc with xp is like this :

192.168.2.11

255.255.255.0

0.0.0.0

empty

empry

computer name : cougar

workgroup : nethome

homeNetwork is disabled (i think that is 4 2 pc's with 7 os not xp)

every thing is off in network options except file & printer sharing in public area

=====================================================================

pc with xp os is like this :

192.168.2.12

255.255.255.0

192.168.2.11 (mean gateway)

4.2.2.4

8.8.8.8

computer name : tiger

workgroup : nethome

=====================================================================

at last my little net is ok...

mean both have internet , both can see each other by their ip (\\192.168.2.11 or \\192.168.2.12)

my problem is when in pc with xp type \\cougar it shows an error about network path!

but in pc with 7 \\tiger works perfec.

what is the problem in system with xp ?

in few days ago this network was ok (search by computer name) when both os were xp , so there is no problem with my cable or devices.

another problem is i can not find tiger in my network list in 7 pc \ why?

is something wrong with my network?

thanks 4 future advance

best regards

Comment: is there any body home?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/249272/simple-network-between-xp-7-with-cross-cable-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from what you are saying that Cougar is your Windows 7 computer. If so the problem you have lies with the changes in security with Windows 7+. You will need to ensure that the windows 7 firewall is configured to allow "File and Print Sharing". You will also need to ensure that you set the folders you wish to share access to are configured correctly both on the share and the NTFS tab.

Do both of your computers belong to the same workgroup? Another issue could be Windows 7 provides device discovery, using the "Networking and Sharing Center" you should check to see if device discovery is enabled.

Also when connecting your windows 7 machine to the network for the first time you will of been presented with a box asking you to identify the type of network connection which is active. This of course should be set to Home.

I have give you a basis to start troubleshooting, please let me know how you get on.

Comment: configured to allow "File and Print Sharing" = enabled 4 both private & public / shared = ok / same workgroup = ok / network discovery = enabled 4 poth private & public / box asking = i did not get this wizard - where is that and how can i do that manually?

Comment: This is done through the network and sharing wizard, it should show your computer and a little topology diagram showing how you connect to the internet. Around there it should say Work/Home/Public

Comment: it seems problem was about file and printer sharing & network discovery & it has solved / but let us to what is difference between private and public in this network ?

Comment: These options are to control network devices seeing your computer. Public as the name implys allows your computer to be discovered where as private does not.